# How to get Woocommerce orders Between Dates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying the following code and want to get all orders between dates and print them

```
 $orders = $my_query->posts;
 $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
 $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
 $order_id = $order_data['id'];
 if ($order_data['date_created']='12-12-2023')
 {
    echo('Order id-'.$order_id.'---order id end here-----');
 }
```

Getting error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_data() on bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try to use this code:

```
$initial_date = yyyy-mm-dd;
$final_date = yyyy-mm-dd;
$orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'limit'=>-1,
    'type'=> 'shop_order',
    'date_created'=> $initial_date .'...'. $final_date 
    )
);
```

`$orders` should now hold all orders between given dates.

Answer (score 3):

It also works with dates that include **hours : minutes : seconds** :

```
$date_a = '2022-08-18 09:45:00';
$date_b = '2022-09-02 19:30:00';

$on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders
(
    array 
    (
    'limit' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'status'    => 'on-hold',
    'date_created'  => strtotime($date_a) .'...'. strtotime($date_b)
    )
);
```